# Profile picture does not update after form submitted in django

Tags: python, django, web, web-development-server

I also created UserUpdateForm class which i did not include here and if i try to change my name and email through UserUpdateForm class it works but if try for profile picture it did not works

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ProfileUpdateForm

def editprofile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
    if u_form.is_valid():
        p_form.save()
        return redirect('profile')

else:
    p_form = UserRegisterForm(instance=request.user.profile)

context = {
    'p_form': p_form,
}
return render(request, 'users/editprofile.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['image']
```

html template

```
<form class="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form__group form__avatar">
                        <label for="avatar">Upload Avatar</label>
                        <input class="form__hide" required type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg"/>
                    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: yeah it won't work because of two reasons:1) you have two forms in the same view `UserRegisterForm and ProfileUpdateForm` and actually i do not really undrestand how you are processing  the data your variable is `p_form` and actually you are verifying `u_form.is_valid()` 2) you are not actually using the form inside the template .fix these two bugs everything should work fine )))

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow
 I think i am doing something wrong in template and everything looks fine, I will try second option and after this I will give you an update

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow hey buddy how are you hope you will be fine. I changed my html template a bit and my form start working.